# Validar que la fecha no se encuentre en el futuro

Tags: javascript, date

En un fichero js, gracias a las ayudas y más investigación, ya he conseguido validar la corrección de una fecha facilitada por el usuario. Como se trata de una fecha de nacimiento me gustaría poder controlar que no fuera superior a la fecha actual.
¿En el siguiente código, como incorporo el control descrito?
Gracias anticipadas.

```
function validaEdat(){
    vesSumant();
    vfalladata = false;

    //Comprovació de la data de naixement i el correu electrònic

    var vregexNaix = /^(((0{0,1}[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([/])(0{0,1}[13578]|10|12)([/])(\d{4}))|((0{0,1}[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)([/])(0{0,1}[469]|11)([/])(\d{4}))|((0{0,1}[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])([/])(0{0,1}2)([/])(\d{4}))|((29)(\.|-|\/)(0{0,1}2)([/])([02468][048]00))|((29)([/])(0{0,1}2)([/])([13579][26]00))|((29)([/])(0{0,1}2)([/])([0-9][0-9][0][48]))|((29)([/])(0{0,1}2)([/])([0-9][0-9][2468][048]))|((29)([/])(0{0,1}2)([/])([0-9][0-9][13579][26])))$/;
 -->

    vdataNaix = document.formu.dataNaix.value;
    vanyData = vdataNaix.substring(vdataNaix.length-4, 4);
    if((!vregexNaix.test(vdataNaix)) || (/^(\d{4})$/.test(vanyData))){
        alert("Bonvolu skribi vera naskighdato per tt/mm/jjjj. \n--------------------------------------\n Per favor, una data vera com dd/mm/aaaa.");
        document.formu.dataNaix.value = "";
        document.formu.dataNaix.focus();
        return false;
    }

    controlaCaselles();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: El hilo referido en el comentario anterior incluye respuestas con validaciones de lado del cliente usando [tag:javascript] las cuáles son prácticamente lo que se requiere para este caso.

Comment: No recomiedo bajo ningún punto de vista utilizar la expresión regular publicada en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo correcto sería poner validaciones al menos en las dos capas: cliente y servidor. Si se manipula la base de datos manualmente, entonces conviene también poner una restricción en la base de datos.

---

Cuando tratas con fechas, tienes que ser muy cuidadoso. No solo tienes que tener en cuenta fechas, si no, en muchos casos, también la zona horaria. Si no tienes en cuenta esto, un usuario en América y otro en Asia pueden ver una fecha diferente.

Existe una librería llamada [moment](https://momentjs.com/), la cual es exepcional y casi elección de facto al tratar con fechas. Moment te permite saber con suma facilidad si la fecha que has ingresado es válida:

```js
const isValidDate = moment('fake date').isValid();
console.log('Is a valid date?:', isValidDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Tan simple como pasarle la fecha a moment y a partir de allí tenemos a disposición muchas funciones para dicha fecha, como sumar o restart dias/semanas/meses/años, formatear, etc (para más información, consultar [la documentación](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Para saber si la fecha no es futura, basta con usar una comparación:

```js
const isPastOrPresent = moment('2017-04-02') <= moment();
console.log('Is past or preset date?:', isPastOrPresent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que deberias empezar por modificar tu HTML algo asi mira:

```
<input id="datefield" type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-13-13'></input>
```

Si te das cuenta Min y max en el tag te permite establecer el rango de fechas que quieres que el usuario pueda escojer la fecha.

Ahora usando un poco de codigo podemos hacerlo con la fecha actual.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
   dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
   mm='0'+mm
} 
today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
```

y eso es todo. te recomiendo no usar el java script, y utilizar un marker de servidor. en ASP.MVC es algo asi

`@DateTime.Now.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd');`

y te lo recomiendo porque si el usuario tiene su fecha desactualizada, o lo modifica el usuario con la finalidad de bugear tu sistema lo hara si usas el java script, encambio si usas un Mark de server tomara la fecha del servidor. 
Saludos!

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dae4y126/)

*Solo es compatible con Chrome, FireFox, IE > 10*